# Update multiple Windows 8 to 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-8-upgrade

My office has multiple Windows 8 Machines and slow internet. Is there a place online I can download the 8.1 upgrade from home on my fast internet so I can do a network or usb install at the office? I don't want to have to download 3GB+ of updates on each and every machine through the Windows store over our slow internet connection.

The Windows 8 PC's in question are OEM Windows 8 Home, upgraded to Windows 8 Pro via the online Pro pack upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

The only way for you is to get the official ISO from MSDN.

These versions are available in MSDN :

- en_windows_8_1_enterprise_x64_dvd_2971902.iso
- en_windows_8_1_pro_vl_x86_dvd_2972633.iso
- en_windows_8_1_pro_n_vl_x86_dvd_2972709.iso
- en_windows_8_1_enterprise_n_x86_dvd_2971850.iso
- en_windows_8_1_pro_vl_x64_dvd_2971948.iso
- en_windows_8_1_enterprise_n_x64_dvd_2971845.iso
- en_windows_8_1_enterprise_x86_dvd_2972289.iso
- en_windows_8_1_pro_n_vl_x64_dvd_2971969.iso

Comment: Could you provide actual links please?

Comment: there are no links, you have to be an MSDN subscriber to get them.

Comment: Will that do in-place upgrade on Win8 Pro Upgrade version I bought for $40 when it was released a year ago?

Comment: yes, it can do in-place upgrade